# Why does a key in a Map must be an object and not a primitive and Why cant i use primitive type as key in a map

Tags: java

I have a map: `Map abc = new HashMap()`. Why is it mandatory for me to use only objects as keys and not primitives?

Comment: Just off the top of my head, I would suggest it might have something to do with the fact that primitives can't generate hash codes...

Comment: Is this even a concern, since we have autoboxing?

Comment: @NilSH Autoboxing will help in case if map is declared as <Integer,Object>  but you cant declare map as <int, Object>.

Comment: Yes, of course. The point was just that even if it is declared <Integer, Object>, you can still use it with int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for why: The implementations of a Map require Object keys (with an `equals()` function) to (efficiently) order/store your values for quick retrieval. Primitives do not have an `equals()` function and are therefore unsuited for the task. (this is basically what @MadProgrammer suggested, except that [`equals` is used in the defintion, and `hashCode` is just optional for possible implementations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)).

There is no reason that it would not be possible to programm this, however: in fact you could argue that primitives have the easiest equality and hashCodes to compute! This is probably what is done in `TIntArrayList` as suggested by Narendra Pathai. And as Jens Schauder states: it would not be worth the hassle, also because autoboxing hides the problem from you most of the time.

Comment: Autoboxing do hide the problem most of the times but doesnt help in declaring map having primitive  type as key.

Comment: The only reason you might want to do this, is if you have a very large map, and so little memory that even the key-objects should be primitives.. In such a case you might want to write your own interface and implementation. I really liked [this course](https://www.coursera.org/course/algs4partI) by the way, and it will teach anyone how to make a HashMap implementation.

Answer (score 3):

In java there is a big divide between primitives and objects/classes.

When you define a method that takes and `Object` as an argument, you might as well pass a String, or a `AbstractSingletonFactoryFacade`. But you can't pass a primitive. There is just no way to abstract over multiple primitives. This didn't change with generics.

What one could do is define separate interfaces accepting (and returning) the various primitives. While this would be feasible for thing like List, which have only one type parameter, for Map with two type parameters you would end up with 81 interfaces ([8 primitive types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) + `Object` squared). Which just isn't worth the hassle.

Of course most of the time this doesn't matter since Autoboxing makes the problem invisible most of the time.

Comment: Also I would like to add that there is a Trove library which does this for collections of primitive type. It has classes like `TIntArrayList` and `TIntCharMap`